# Google Chrome Extensions Linking with a Website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just had a small query regarding extensions in chrome. 
I have already developed a chrome extension for my portfolio website. I somehow don't know how to put across a prompt to embed the chrome extension into the browser. (install option). For better clarity over the issue please refer to the screenshot below.
[Screenshot depicting the prompt on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEZPv.png)

Comment: That prompt is not for an extension, but for a [PWA](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/). You can't install extensions this way. Extensions can only be installed from the web store.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I think that will solve the problem. Thank you everyone